# Rails push into array saves object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an interesting problem. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.3.

I have 2 models, for simplification let's say customers and stores.
Stores have many customers, and a customer belongs to a store.
I'm trying to collect all customers for a store, and create a place for a few more that I can populate with values later. Instead, customer.save is called when I don't expect it.

```
store = Store.find(1)
customers_array = store.customers
random_array = Array.new
customers_count = customers_array.count + 1 

(customers_count..2).each do |i|
  customer = Customer.new
  c.id = "#{i}000000000000"
  random_array << customer # this line doesn't call customer.save
  customers_array << customer # this line calls customer.save when store has customers
end
```

For some reason when the customer is pushed into the array, customer.save is called.
It doesn't happen if you push to an array is a plain array and not a relation.

I found a workaround, but I'm still wondering why that happens.
The workaround:

```
store = Store.find(1)
initial_customers_array = store.customers
additional_customers_array = Array.new
customers_count = initial_customers_array.count + 1 

(customers_count..2).each do |i|
  customer = Customer.new
  c.id = "#{i}000000000000"
  additional_customers_array << customer 
end
customers_array = initial_customers_array + additional_customers_array
```

Comment: For those looking for a solution and not the why: use ```build``` on the collection to create a model without saving it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collections

Comment: I had the opposite problem. Using `build` in model specs, then adding items to a collection using << did not work. The answers to this question explain why not.

Answer (score 22):

`<<` is an alias for `push`

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/%3C%3C
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/push

which in the `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` calls `concat`

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat *(view the source of the method)*
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L283

which calls `concat_records`

- http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat_records

where you can see the insert taking place.

So, with an existing record *(persisted into the database)*, running `<<` or `.push` will insert records into the collection, persisting them to the database if necessary. Calling `<<` on an Array, not the record collection, as you're doing in

```
random_array << customer
```

calls Ruby's `<<` Array method, not the AR equivalent *(as you found, no save takes place in this case)*.

**Edit:** To be clear, the workaround you found is more or less how I typically handle the situation you're dealing with; my answer focuses more on *why* `<<` has this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Another way around this would be to change your second line (of your original code) to:

```
customers_array = store.customers.to_a
```

That casts the active record association to a real array object, so the `<<` method will be the normal Array#push method.