# Related object not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have the models:

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections, :class_name => 'IdeaConnection', :foreign_key => 'idea_a_id', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ideas, :through => :connections, :source => :idea_b, :dependent => :destroy
end

class IdeaConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea
  belongs_to :idea_a, :class_name => 'Idea'
  belongs_to :idea_b, :class_name => 'Idea'
  belongs_to :relationship
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :idea_connections 
end
```

Idea, as you can see, own itself through Connections (join table). Each Connection entry belongs to Relationship. What I'm trying to do is to, after adding an Idea to another with:

```
Idea.find(1).ideas << Idea.find(2)
```

which is working and saving properly, get its connection on join table and update its relationship:

Ex:

```
Idea.find(1).connections.find_by_idea_b_id(Idea.f
ind(2).id).relationship = Relationship.find(1)
```

It processes correctly but it won't save.

Please, help, what am I missing?

ps: I don't want to do it by manually editting the relationship_id since it's ugly.
ps2: Before you answer, remember the fact that autosave:true do not work for belongs_to/has_many relationships.

Comment: So, are you saving `Idea`? Try to define `connection = Idea.find(1).connections.first`, set relationship and save it.

Comment: The relation is already saved. Firstly I create the relation, then I try to make it belong to a Relationship, but for some reason that I can't understand, it doesn's saves it on DB.

Comment: Ah.. and I already tried what you are saying... no luck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with connection object. Remember it.
Your problem is that you call `find_by...` method in `has_many` association. It returns one record BUT Idea model has no ruby attribute link to that. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L77) why. That's why `Idea#save` cannot call `IdeaConnection#save` (remember that for cascade saving `connections` realtion must have autosave: true if connection already exists).

So I suggest you two options:

1. Set `:inverse_of` on `Idea#connections` and `IdeaConnection#idea_a` relations and preload all records before mangling with `Idea.find(1).connections.find_by_idea_b_id(Idea.f
   ind(2).id).relationship = Relationship.find(1)`. But I don't recommend you to do so because:
2. As I said you're working with connection object. Just do so:

   ```
   Idea.find(1).connections.create do |connection|
     connection.idea_b = Idea.find(2)
     connection.relationship = Relationship.first
   end
   ```

Comment: nice answer... tecnical... but let me ask you something... ruby meant to be beautiful and even looking tecnically correct, this is not quite an ellegant solution... is it philosophically corret?

Comment: Absolutely. Because it agrees with your domain model and business logic. You have two ideas. And you create a _connection_ between them.

Comment: You are still able to add some syntantic sugar to ActiveRecord and delegate creating logic to Idea model. Like this: `def connect_idea(idea); connections.create {|c| c.idea_b = idea; c.relationship = Relationship.first} end` but it is only a wrapper. You cannot create something else using ActiveRecord pattern. Alternative is DataMapper but there is no good gem for this pattern now.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code won't save it

```
Idea.find(1).connections.first.relationship = Relationship.first
```

What you need to do is:

Method #1: ( add the connection to the has_many relation )

```
Relationship.first.idea_connections << Idea.find(1).connections.first
```

OR

Method #2: ( add relationship_id to the connection then manually save it)

```
connection = Idea.find(1).connections.first
connection.relationship_id = Relationship.first.id
connection.save
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your idea, so it will be more helpful for other visitors and the OP himself.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to propose but you are missing the point.  Your first method couldnt work since you are adding and object to itself. THe Connection model do not own itself, only the Idea model. Relationship is another relation that I'm creating with the join table. The join table entry belongs to the model Relationship.

Comment: Forgot to comment about the second method: The second method is what I'm using, but it's ugly. lol

Comment: I understand the second looks ugly :D . But I see that both do the same job, can you clear your point?

Comment: I want to do this properly. If rails have a right way to implement this, I want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assignments on the relational object level don't/won't automatically save; you have to tell them to. In ActiveRecord the push method (<<) has save built into it, which is why that was working for you. Setting a value (=) however does not have save built in, so you have to do it manually.

If you're interested, here's a link to another SO question where an answer talks about why push saves: [Rails push into array saves object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043096/rails-push-into-array-saves-object)

Comment: I understand this, but .save aren't saving the object either. What's the correct way to save.

Comment: The question is not why it's not saving, but how to save it correctly accordingly with rails philosophy.