# How to append an element to an array using update command in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's my code

```
project.reports << report
project.save
```

I want to write a single update command instead of these two lines. Something like

```
project.update(reports << report)
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Was there something like `project.create(report)` with `has_many :reports` mapping?

Comment: `project.reports << report` should save both objects I believe

Comment: @Smar, Mapping already there in model. However, I am implementing this as a part of services.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, It seems to be working, but how?

Comment: Okay in this case @MichalSzyndel is correct... AmanGupta: I guess it worked correctly even first; the API may be a bit unintuitive here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have association like Project has many Reports, then simply using

```
project.reports << report
```

will call save too. No need to call project.save seperately.

Comment: This seems to be a correct answer, but I never saw such thing in rails guide. Can you give me some online reference related to this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043096/rails-push-into-array-saves-object . I also verified it on a local project, it works.

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect!